# How do I find a public key ID in terminal?

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

I added this key to my system:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

But I didn't like it and tried to delete it manually and doing it wrong actually, so I got GPG key error `NO_PUB_KEY...` after running `apt-get update`. I got a whole bunch of public keys so:

I ran:

```
apt-key list | grep google*
```

but it shows me only Google `uid` but no `pub` and I need `pub` to run `apt-key del`.

So what do I need to add/edit to this command line `apt-key list | grep google*` so it search for Google `pub`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your terminal and type as

```
apt-key list
```

It will list all the keys you have added with its public key ID's. I have tried your way I have seen the Google pub ID

```
abcdefgg@abcdefgg-virtual-machine:~$ wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
[sudo] password for abcdefgg: 
OK
abcdefgg@abcdefgg-virtual-machine:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
abcdefgg@abcdefgg-virtual-machine:~$ apt-key list | grep google*
uid                  Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
abcdefgg@abcdefgg-virtual-machine:~$ apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/EFE21092 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   1024D/3E5C1192 2010-09-20
uid                  Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

pub   1024D/7FAC5991 2007-03-08
uid                  Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   2048g/C07CB649 2007-03-08

abcdefgg@abcdefgg-virtual-machine:~$
```

Comment: Thank you! I see that, but I also thought if it were possible to find its `pub` with `grep` that will show only `pubs` ID keys for `Google` because when running `apt-key list | grep pub` it lists all pubs but with no name to what this key referes to. :-)